# Display Missing Rows from Tables of MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two data table one is :

"cards" Table which Contains :

```
   id                           Department
0000022288                      COR 
0000043880                      NA  
0000031643                      NA  
0000013870                      TRAN
0000053900                      COR 
0000055452                      IOR 
0000010957                      IOR 
0000025746                      BILL
0000061783                      BILL
0000000773                      NA
```

I have another table (valid_entry):

```
date         emp_id    emp_time
20130101    0000002001  101825    
20130102    0000002001  085024    
20130103    0000002001  085657    
20130106    0000002001  095145    
20130107    0000002001  090724    
20130108    0000002001  091244
```

I want to display those id which are not in valid table.

my query:

```
SELECT  emp_valid_date
    ,   emp_valid_name
    ,   emp_valid_time
    ,   emp_valid_dept
    ,   Name
FROM valid_entry
INNER JOIN Cards ON emp_valid_dept = Depart_Code
WHERE emp_valid_date = '$date'
    AND emp_valid_time >= 060000
    AND emp_valid_time <= 230000
    AND emp_valid_dept != 'DRI' OR emp_valid_time = ''
```

It will be okey if I can get something like:

```
date         emp_id    emp_time card_id_missing
20130101    0000002001  101825    
20130102                        0000002001  
20130103    0000002001  085657    
20130106    0000002001  095145    
20130107    0000002001  090724    
20130108    0000002001  091244
```

I want something like this

Comment: Please add the missing columns and rename the existing ones in the sample in your `valid_entry` table to match your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
    SELECT ID from Cards C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN valid_entry VE
    ON C.ID = VE.emp_id
    WHERE VE.emp_id IS NULL
```

IF you need to display all the rows, then remove the `WHERE` clause. It will return all the rows, but NULL for rows in cards but not in valid_entry

Raj

Comment: i have tried it but it is returning the rows which are not existed in valid_entry. i want valid_entry+cards (existed+not existed)

Comment: yeah it is displaying the result but only from the cards table but it is not showing the data from valid_entry

Comment: Include all the columns you want to see in the `SELECT` list

Comment: please check my last update what i want exactly. just want to add a new column contains missing from Cards Table in valid_entry. hope that you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM cards WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT emp_id FROM valid entry)
```

Comment: sorry no use. i want the data from valid_entry also want to include the rows from cards which are not existed in valid_entry table.

Comment: Ah ok. Then Raj solution with an outer join is the correct solution.

Comment: i have tried it but it is returning the rows which are not existed in valid_entry. i want valid_entry+cards (existed+not existed)

Comment: In that case, remove the `WHERE` clause in my query. It will return all the rows, but NULL for rows in cards but not in valid_entry

Comment: do you think it will return the data of valid_entry also

Comment: yeah it is displaying the result but only from the cards table but it is not showing the data from valid_entry